# Absolute url overwiritten as a Relative URl when adding a new html element like iframe etc (i.e adding the a base address at prefix of URL supplied)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an iframe to my website. The problem is that our CMS automatically overrides the src address given ex: I set the absolute url (source address) to http://www.youtube.com/embed/RE6C1AoWy3M and when the page is rendered the src is modified as shown.

The base address is being added. This was set as we normaly upload images/files on our file system. 
Any idea how can I override this, maybe embed some javascript function. I do not have access to .cs/ Asp.net  pages.

Comment: _when the page is rendered the src is modified as shown_ as shown where? what is result. Example of modified url, example of html,javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has finally worked. I am creating the iFrame as shown below not using the CMS drag/drop html  objects and modify the src attribute.

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
el.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
// Here I am getting the object to append the iframe to
var elem = document.getElementById("td1");  
// Append iframe to this element.
elem.appendChild(el);
el.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/RE6C1AoWy3M');
</script>
```

Although this solved my problem, I am open to new maybe better suggestions. I am willing to learn from other's experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inline script that will render the iframe during the page load.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Your normal HTML/text here -->
<!-- add the script where you wanted the iframe to be -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.write("<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/RE6C1AoWy3M'></iframe>");
</script>
<!-- Your remaining HTML/text here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a demo link that you can share with us? It would be pretty helpful to understand what is going on.